# I want my page so the divs don't move around on browser window resize

Tags: html, css

My page is http://celldivine.000webhostapp.com/ , don't kill me for the free domain. So anyway, whenever I use a different to visit the site the site becomes deformed and everything moves around. I want to make it not so that all the divs resize, but so that they stay exactly the same, and users with a smaller resolution can just side scroll to see it. I know you can probably do this in your sleep. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you use a different ... what? to use the site? Please add your code to your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to CSS (but change the width value to what you want:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1500px;
}
```

Then add

```
<div class="wrapper">
```

after the

```
<a href="index.html">
```

and

```
</div>
```

before the

```
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may use twitter bootstrap Grid System to create a responsive site  http://getbootstrap.com/ 
for more details http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html and  https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-responsive-layout.php